# Serialization of an object and its Contained Objects

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

There is a main class having 2 subClasses(each represent separate entity) and all classes needs to be serialized.. how should I proceed ? 
My requirement is when I serelize MainClass, I should get the xml for each sub class and main class as well.   Thanks in advance... and if my approach is incorrect... correct that as well..

Ex given below...

```
class MainClass
{
   SubClass1 objSubclass1 = null;   
   SubClass2 objSubclass2 = null;
   public MainClass()
   {
     objSubclass1 = new SubClass1();
     objSubclass2 = new SubClass2();
   }
   [XmlElement("SubClass1")]
   public SubClass1 SubClass1 {get {return objSubclass1;} }
   [XmlElement("SubClass2")]
   public SubClass2 SubClass2 {get {return objSubclass2;} }
}

Class SubClass1
{
  Some properties here...
}

Class SubClass2
{
  Some properties here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XML serialization to work with properties, you need to have both getters and setters for the properties.

Also, generally when the term subclass is used, it means a class that derives from a base class.  This doesn't seem to be the case here so your example is a bit confusing.

If you actually do need to serialize subclasses, where the static type of a property is a base class, see the [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

XML serialization requires the properties to be read/write. So you need to implement the `get` *and* `set`.

If you don't like that restriction, then you can implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) (there's an example on the linked page), but it's probably more trouble than it's worth for such a simple requirement I would think.